# Returning from submethod from super

Tags: java, super

I have something like this:

```
class SuperClass {
  public void onClick(){
    if(disabled) return;
  }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  public void onClick(){
    super.onClick();
    System.out.println("Clicked");
  }
}
```

This outputs "Clicked" every time I click the button.

I want the SubClass onClick() to not work if disabled is true and don't want to add an extra line in every SubClass. How can I do that?

Comment: Where/How do you set the disabled status?

Comment: @DrColossos In the super class. That's not the problem. The problem is that when i return from the method in the superclass, it only returns from the super method and not the method in the subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate to another method:

```
class SuperClass {
  public void onClick(){
    if(!disabled) handleOnClick();
  }
  public void handleOnClick(){
  }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  public void handleOnClick(){
    System.out.println("Clicked");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

```
abstract class SuperClass {
  public void onClick(){
    if(!disabled) clickAction() ;
  }

  public abstract void clickAction();
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  public void clickAction(){
    System.out.println("Clicked");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
class SuperClass {
  public void onClick(){
    if(disabled) return;
    processClick();
  }
  protected void processClick() {
  }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  protected void processClick(){
    super.processClick();
    System.out.println("Clicked");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't not this way anyway. The function call in the super object doesn't have any right to  do anything to stop the method in the subclass from executing. What you're looking for is a [TemplateMethodPattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern maybe. You could have something like this

```
 abstract class SuperClass {
  public void onClick(){
    if(disabled) return;
    doClick();
  }

  protected abstract void doClick();

}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  protected void doClick(){  
    System.out.println("Clicked");
  }
}
```